# How to fix "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" in Python with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tkinter interface with Python 3.7.2, and it gives out:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

I need to take content from `Edit's` and multiply them by showing them on `Label`.

I tried using `int` but I'm using number '2.5'

```py
def count():
    x = float(EditBox1_text.get())
    y = float(EditBox2_text.get())
    return x * y

EditBox1_text = StringVar(0)
EditBox2_text = StringVar(0)

EditBox1 = Entry(MainActivity, textvariable=EditBox1_text).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
EditBox2 = Entry(MainActivity, textvariable=EditBox2_text).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: just check type of `EditBox2_text.get()` and it's value

Comment: Empty string, probably

Comment: `EditBox1_text = StringVar(0)`, what does that even do?

Comment: EditBox2_text.get() is text from EditBox2 (Entry2)

Comment: if you `print(EditBox2_text.get())` what do you see?

Comment: EditBox1(2) is used to get text from Entry, that inputs user.

Comment: i see a space))

Comment: also `print(type(EditBox2_text.get()))` ?

Comment: `EditBox2_text.get()` is empty string.

Comment: Well you can't very well convert nothing to a float

Comment: type string, but EditBox text does not changing from code

Comment: Are you inputting numbers into the boxes before calling the `float()` method with them?

Comment: Program doesn't even start

Comment: ...

You may want to try that first. Walk before you can run, kid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm tried this, and it's worked:

```
def count():
    x = float(EditBox1_text.get())
    y = float(EditBox2_text.get())
    AnswerText_text.set(x * y)
```

Before, i called

```
AnswerText_text.set(count())
```

At run of code

Answer (score -1):

Tkinter constructor of `StringVar` takes no value argument, unless if pointed as a keyword argument, as pointed by @BryanOakley, So, you cannot initialize `StringVar` with a value without the keyword argument declared. For that you have to use `.set`, to set the variable value, as so:

```
EditBox1_text = StringVar()
EditBox2_text = StringVar()

EditBox1_text.set("2.5")
EditBox2_text.set("3.8")
```

Comment: _"Tkinter constructor of StringVar takes no value argument"_ - that is an incorrect statement. You can initialize it, but you need to specify it as a keyword argument: `StringVar(value="hello")`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, you are correct, I have updated the answer including your comments.